# Cannot extract data with multiple LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, sql, slim

I need to extract all the countries which are matches that play into a specific date, the table structure is this:

```
TABLE NAME  |  FIELDS
country     | id, name  
round       | id, season_id
season      | id, competition_id
competition | id, country_id
match       | id, round_id, date
```

a single `match` record have the following composition:

```
id: 60856
round_id: 65
date: 2018-06-02 00:00:00
```

as you can see I've the `round_id` where the `match` is disputed.
On the `round` table there is the following design:

```
id: 65
season_id: 280
```

the `season` represent the container of the `round`, so a `season` record have this structure:

```
id: 161
competition_id: 48
```

and a `season` have a `competition` that contains all the `rounds`. A `competition` record contains the `country`:

```
id: 48
coutry_id: 2
```

and finally the `country`:

```
id: 2
name: albania
```

How can I extract all the countries that have matches which playing today?

This is what I tried:

```
$app->get('/country/get_countries/{date}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM country
      LEFT JOIN `match` ON round_id = round.id
      LEFT JOIN round ON season_id = season.id
      LEFT JOIN season ON competition_id = competition.id
      WHERE match.datetime = " . $args["date"] . "");

    $sql->execute();
    $countries = $sql->fetchAll();
    return $response->withJson($countries);
});
```

this will return:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'round.id' in 'on clause'

UPDATE:

```
  $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM country
  LEFT JOIN competition ON country_id = competition.country_id
  LEFT JOIN competition_seasons ON competition_id = competition.id
  LEFT JOIN competition_rounds ON competition_rounds.season_id = competition_seasons.id
  LEFT JOIN `match` ON match.round_id = competition_rounds.id
  WHERE match.datetime = " . $args["date"] . "");
```

Comment: because you left join on the match table not on the round table,very bad model formation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM country
      LEFT JOIN competition ON country.id = competition.country_id
      LEFT JOIN season ON season.competition_id= competition.id
      LEFT JOIN round ON round.season_id= season.id
      LEFT JOIN match ON match.round_id= round.id
      WHERE match.datetime = " . $args["date"] . ""
```

Comment: nope, the table country doesn't have such columns, I updated my query and now seems to work but unfortunately return no result and this is really strange

Comment: mmm is possible var_dump the variable `$args` using slim? If I use var_dump nothing is displayed

Comment: what is slim return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172304/discussion-between-charanoglu-and-eminem).